# how to hot reload component with ts and vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Every code I changed on the .ts file will trigger the browser refresh, and I do not want it work this way. I have tried many solutions like "vue-ts-loader", "vue-hot-reload-api",..., but I have not found a good one. How you guys fixed this issue?

Comment: I used the following template https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript for just a try. You also may check out and check, it might help you

Comment: The author use .html as template. I have already used .vue

Answer (score 0):

Like Suresh Velusamy said: try [github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript](http://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript) .
It works out of the box.

Instead of requiring the template file, just put the template inline. Works fine.

```
    @Component({
    template: `<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="content col-md-4">
        <h1>
          <strong>Thank you the fish
            <span class="text-primary package">{{package}}</span>
          </strong>
        </h1>
        <p>This project is running in
          <strong class="mode">{{mode}} mode</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Make sure to follow the project on
          <a :href="repo">GitHub</a> to stay up to date with the latest releases,
          or contribute to the project by opening an issue
          or making a pull-request!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`})
```